# DB Will Not Render from php Script

Tags: php, mysql

Good evening...

Typical newbie to php issues here. This is for a personal project, not a college student looking for a solution, and need to render a database from my website. The code below is being housed in a Wordpress website and you will the shortcode, in place of , that is utilized by the WP plug-in.

I have verified my database access information with my hosting company and I know that isn't the issue..

The issue I am having is that I am getting the die message; "cannot retrieve your request".

The DEFINE variables have been verified with Laughing Squid and should be correct. You will see a series of echo functions to see where exactly the issue may be when the script runs and I am getting all the way through "connection test 3" and "connection test 4" never renders.

If I enter search criteria in the page I get the "fancy meeting you here message".

Any help is greatly appreciated....

//SCRIPT FOLLOWS

```
<html>
<head>
   <style/type = "text/css">

     table {
      background-color: #FCF;
     }

     th {
     width: 150px;
     text-align: left;
    }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Race Search</h1>


<form method = "post" action="search.php"> 
<input type = "hidden" name = "submitted" value = "true"/>

<label> Search Race: 

<select name = "race">
   <option value = "date">Race Date</option>
   <option value = "city">Location</option>
   <option value = "race">Race</option>
</select>
</label>

<label>Search Criteria: <input type="text" name="criteria" /></label>

</form>

//short code from Wordpress plug-in
[allowphp useadvancedfilter]



DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'Removed');
DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', 'Removed');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'Removed');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'Removed');

$dbcon = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME);

//connection test 1
echo "connection1";

$race = $_POST['race'];
$criteria = $_POST['criteria'];

//connection test 2
echo "connection2";
$query  = "SELECT * FROM Races WHERE $category = '$criteria'";

//connection test 3
echo "connection3";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die('Cannot retrieve your request');

//connection test 4, never gets here....
echo "connection4";
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows results found";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Race Date</th><th>Location</th><th>Event</th> </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

     echo "<tr><td>";
     echo $row['Date'];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['City'];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['Race Name'];
     echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

//short code from Wordpress plug-in
 [/allowphp useadvancedfilter]


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` say?

Comment: @JohnConde mysqli_error*. Edit. Just realized OP is using both.

Comment: @JohnConde based on the syntax the mysql_error is a function to return however, I am not using that in the script. Are you suggesting to add this function. It the moment I am getting no error, only getting the "cannot retrieve your request" from the die(); function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using mysql_connect with mysqli_query. You should be using mysqli_connect, they are not interchangeable.

If you can update your select option values to match your column names, you could use something like this:

```
$where = '';
if (isset($_POST['race'])) {
    $race = $POST['race'];
    $where = ' WHERE `'.$race."` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['criteria'])."'";
}
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `Races`'.$where;
```

If not that will still work, but you'll need to use a switch statement or something to set $race to the correct value to match your column name. You may want to do that anyhow to ensure that $_POST['race'] is an expected value.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @tchshields...however I made the edit and still no table...I changed the mysql_connect to the mysqli_connect. Should I changed all the script to mysqli_ or mysql_

Comment: Is $category actually a column name? Is that variable set?
`$query  = "SELECT * FROM Races WHERE $category = '$criteria'";`

Comment: @user3413142 regarding mysql_ vs msyqli_, mysqli has existed since PHP 5, mysql_ is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. So as long as you're using at least PHP 5 you should be using mysqli.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. So, no $category needs to not be a variable. I want users to have the option to search race date, city, race name. Also have the table render all rows regardless if there is a search. My columns are Date, City, Race Name . Also I changed it all back to mysqli_